# Ordered Probit/Logit with random coefficients

Tags: r, ordinal

I searched everywhere but I didn't find what I want, that is why I as the question here. Does anybody know of a function in `R` which allows to estimate ordered probit/logit model with `random coefficients`.

The only mixed effect model I found was `clmm` of the `ordinal`package but it only provides random intercepts. I am grateful for every hint!

Comment: if you don't get anything here in a day or two, maybe worth asking on `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org`.  If necessary you could probably put together your own solution based on the basic recipe for parameterizing ordered models (see e.g. Faraway on generalized models, Venables and Ripley).

Comment: @Jilber: I don't get why every phrase of politeness is edited away here on stackoverflow.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for taking a look at my question! The answer: The `MCMCglmm` package provides a bayesian version of an ordinal regression with a probit link function.

Comment: it would be polite to say that you got this information from posters on the r-sig-mixed-models mailing list ... e.g. http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.lme4.devel

Comment: @ Ben Bolker: I considered it, but please read your comment above, or the link you posted below my question, why any form of politeness is edited out on stackoverflow. In my opinion this form of communication, where every form of cordiality is left out, is weird, but when the majority of people think it is more efficient like that, then I will stick to it.

Comment: I don't think it's "any form of politeness edited out".  I interpret it as "introductions and salutations". (And if you really want maximal efficiency, then I guess you should edit out the first sentence of your answer too ...)

Comment: @ Ben Bolker When I look at the history of all my questions on stackoverflow stuff like that always got edited out. Maybe I am old-fashioned but stuff as introduction/salutation formalities make communication more human.But you are right the credit goes to the guys on news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.lme4.devel .

Comment: In any case, the discussion on the meta post I cited does suggest that there's a lot of variability in people's opinions, even if the majority/consensus is for editing out that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do ordered logistic regression is to expand your data. For instance, if you have:

let | cat
----|-----
a   | cat3
b   | cat5

You can expand that to:

let pass level
   a   T    aboveCat0
   a   T    aboveCat1
   a   T    aboveCat2
   a   F    aboveCat3
   a   F    aboveCat4
   b   T    aboveCat0
   b   T    aboveCat1
   b   T    aboveCat2
   b   T    aboveCat3
   b   T    aboveCat4

...and then use "level" as a fixed effect.

Header | Header
------ | ------
Cell   | Cell